# How to change localhost:8000 to laravel.dev

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using apache on Mac os x, laravel 5.2 and my project is currently running on localhost:8000, I want to change this to laravel.dev  Or start a new project with the project-name.dev url. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you install Laravel Valet

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet

It will automatically enable project-name.dev for each project you create in the specified directory.  It makes starting new projects a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

You  have to change the `hosts` file for this. You can set the mappings right in your hosts file. You can read more about it here [Hosts File & Why to use it ?](https://www.imore.com/how-edit-your-macs-hosts-file-and-why-you-would-want)

Comment: thank you ! ,but I found that installing valet is more convenient

Comment: Yes ,you are right ! Valet is just perfect solution laravel provides for Mac OS. Indeed the other solution is much better and convenient :)